# Index out of bounds for a 2D Array?

Tags: python

I am having a 2D List and i am trying to retrieve a column with the index spcified as a parameter (type : `IntEnum`).
I get the `index out of bounds` error when trying to retrieve any column other then the one at index `0`.

**Enum:**

```
class Column(IntEnum):
    ROAD = 0
    SECTION = 1
    FROM = 2
    TO = 3
    TIMESTAMP = 4
    VFLOW=5 

class TrafficData:
    data=[[]]
```

Below are member methods of *TrafficData*

**Reading from file and storing the matrix:**

```
def __init__(self,file):
    self.data=[[word for word in line.split('\t')]for line  in file.readlines()[1:]]
```

**Retrieve-ing the desired column:**

```
def getColumn(self,columnName):
    return [line[columnName] for line in self.data]
```

**Call:**
     )

```
   column1 = traficdata.getColumn(columnName=Column.ROAD)
  `column2 = traficdata.getColumn(columnName=Column.FROM)`  //error
  `column3 = traficdata.getColumn(columnName=Column.TO)`   //error
```

I attached a picture with the data after `__init__` processing:
[image]

[

Comment: would `return [line[int(columnName)] for line in self.data] ` work? (havent seen this IntEnum yet) or `columnName.value`

Comment: I tried so far casting it to int /using IntEnum.value property to no avail.Calling other column gets out of range.

Comment: guessing at least one of the lines in the file is erroneos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the code that you provided above, and didn't see any issues. That leads me to believe that there might be something wrong with the data that you have in the file. Could you paste the file data? (the tab delimited data)

UPDATE - 
I found the issue - as suspected, it was a data issue (there is a minor code update involved too). Make the following changes -

1) When opening the file use the appropriate encoding, I used utf-16.

2) At the end of the data file that you shared, it contains the text - "(72413 row(s) affected)" along with a couple of new line characters. So, you have 2 options, either manually cleanup the data file, or update the code to ignore the "(72413 row(s) affected)" & "\n" characters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1913744 Were you able to resolve the issue using the updated answer?

Comment: Hello again today i managed to solve it.It was as you and others pointed out  the data was incorrect.I changed to filtering method to : self.data=[[word for word in line.split('\t')]for line  in file.readlines()[1:] if len(line.split('\t'))>5]